# Twitter CrossDomain.xml Issue

Tags: twitter, unity-game-engine

Hello Everyone,

I have one problem using twitter for Unity3d Web Player.
When i call for Access Token it always give me Error .
The Error line is basically ,Rejected because CrossDomain.xml file was not found. The Source Code is here :-

```
#region OAuth Token Methods

    // 1. Get Request-Token From Twitter
    // 2. Get PIN from User
    // 3. Get Access-Token from Twitter
    // 4. Use Accss-Token for APIs requriring OAuth 
    // Accss-Token will be always valid until the user revokes the access to your application.
    // Twitter APIs for OAuth process
    private static readonly string RequestTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    private static readonly string AuthorizationURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token={0}";
    private static readonly string AccessTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";

    public static IEnumerator GetRequestToken(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, RequestTokenCallback callback)
    {
        WWW web = WWWRequestToken(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        yield return web;
        Debug.Log ("Web  ****   "+web.error);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(web.error))
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("GetRequestToken - failed. error : {0}", web.error)); // **here it gives error rejected because no cross domain.xml policy file was found.**
            callback(false, null);
        }
        else
        {
            RequestTokenResponse response = new RequestTokenResponse
            {
                Token = Regex.Match(web.text, @"oauth_token=([^&]+)").Groups[1].Value,
                TokenSecret = Regex.Match(web.text, @"oauth_token_secret=([^&]+)").Groups[1].Value,
            };
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Token) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.TokenSecret))
            {
                callback(true, response);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("GetRequestToken - failed. response : {0}", web.text));
                callback(false, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Unity's webplayer sandbox requires that the origin of the request and the url called be on the same domain OR ALTERNATIVELY the url requested have a file called `crossdomain.xml` present in the root directory of the url. You can find more info here http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html

Comment: Now what i have to do for getting  a solution . Can you please describe in deep with an  example.